# Input text = массив.Связующая таблица

Tags: php, массивы, input

```
$FIO_author=array();
foreach($_POST['FIO_author'] as $key=>$value){
$FIO_author[] = "('', '$value','".es($_POST['alias'])."')";
}
$sql2 = q("INSERT INTO author_book(id_author,FIO,alias) VALUES". implode(',', $FIO_author));
$id_author= DB::_()->insert_id;
$sql = q("INSERT INTO book SET
        id_book = '',
        date_add = '".es(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))."',       
        title_book = '".es($_POST['title_book'])."',
        annot_book = '".es($_POST['annot_book'])."',
        descr_book = '".es($_POST['descr_book'])."'");
$id_book= DB::_()->insert_id;
$sql3 = q("INSERT INTO book_and_author(id_book,id_author) VALUES('".$id_book."','".$id_author."')");
```

В связующую таблицу не добавляется второй id_author.
То есть добавляется первый id_author = '249', но второй id_author = 250 не добавляется к одному и тому же id_book = '200' в связующей таблице book_and_author;
p.s. Это я примерно. И вопрос звучит как добавить второй id_author к тому же id_book?

Comment: как же вам помочь, если для работы с базой вы используете какой-то самописный класс (зачем он вам кстати ?) если у вас там mysqli то читайте [вот этот комент](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php#64809)